# Problems using listings package

Tags: listings

I'm using the `listings` package to include some source code files in a LaTeX document.

I'm having 2 problems:

1. characters - are not shown in the resulting file
2. characters % are shown overlapped with characters that appear after it.

This is my `lstset`:

```
\lstset{
showstringspaces=false,
extendedchars=true,
frameround=fttt,
frame=single,
upquote=true,
breaklines=true
}
```

And this is how I insert listings:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
{\small{
\lstinputlisting[language=Python,numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny]{modProblem.txt}
\caption{\label{fig:modProblem} El problema del operador \%}
}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. Moreover the command \lstinputlisting has the option caption.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  In this case it will actually help to ensure that the solution actually solves your specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

Tried to make you [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\lstset{
showstringspaces=false,
extendedchars=true,
frameround=fttt,
frame=single,
upquote=true,
breaklines=true
}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[caption=El problema del operador \%  resuelto,language=Python,numbers=left, numberstyle=\small]{primes.py}
\end{document}
```

It produces normal output (on Windows, using both pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX on TexWorks):

[image: Listing of Python code]

**Only thing that needed to be added** was `\usepackage{textcomp}` in order to use `upquote=true,`.